# How to queue multiple file move operations in Windows?

Tags: windows, nas, file-transfer

#### Background

I have a NAS that stores large backup files on my network : `\\nas.mydomain.local\Share1` and `\\nas.mydomain.local\Share2`. Both shares reside on the same local volume so share the same physical space. The volume is about 80% full, but this is fine b/c old backups get deleted when new ones are created.

#### The problem

I need to move a folder full of backups from one share to the other via a **Windows Server 2012 R2** machine on the network b/c the NAS does not support doing this locally.

If I try to move the folder (or a large selection of files) all at once, Windows complains that `There is not enough space on Share2. You need an additional xxx GB to copy these files.` I understand that windows needs to copy the files before deleting them from the source.

Unfortunately, although there is enough space for a few files, Windows want's to copy the entire set before deleting any of the original files. This means the space from the already copied files isn't freed up again until after the whole set is copied, and there's not enough room to do this.

I can move files individually but then I'm stuck monitoring the progress and starting each new file when the previous one completes. This isn't feasible b/c each file can take several hours and I have many files to copy.

#### The question

How can I queue all of the files to be moved one after the other without Windows complaining about the insufficient space?

I can't install any 3rd party software on this machine b/c it's a server, and I'd prefer to do the copy via this machine b/c it's the only one that has a 10Gbps connection to the NAS.

#### Update 1

The PowerShell command `Get-ChildItem '\\nas3.mydomain.local\Share1\FolderName\' | Move-Item -Destination '\\nas3.mydomain.local\Share1\FolderName\'` works fine, but I'm looking for a GUI solution so I delegate this to someone less comfortable with command line/scripting next time.

I would also prefer to be able to keep an eye on the progress if possible.

#### Update 2

<strike>It also appears that while a Windows UI move preserves each file's Date Modified timestamp, the PowerShell copy doesn't. While this is not a problem for my current task, it might be in other scenarios.</strike> PowerShell appears to update the last modified date after the file copy is complete, so this point is no longer valid.

Comment: Write a batch script?

Comment: @DavidPostill yes, I could write a PowerShell script, but I was hoping for a Windows feature I was unaware of so I can delegate this to someone not comfortable with scripting next time :-) I'll update my question to reflect this.

Comment: Are you _absolutely certain_ this cannot be done locally on the NAS?

Comment: I couldn't find anything in the interface, and [the manual](https://manual.buffalo.jp/buf-doc/35021131-28_EN.pdf) doesn't show any way to manage the files locally. There is no support for ssh that I could find either.